# C++, receive SOCK_DGRAM over UDP IPC with unknown size

Tags: c++, udp, recv

I need to be able to listen on IPC UDP socket and receive messages with unknown size (in C++). Those messages are serialized capnp with some dynamic arrays.

`recv(socket_fd, buff, buff_len, 0)`

How do I size my receive buffer properly?

Can I check what is the message size of the next packet in the queue and resize buffer accordingly?
Is it much overhead to check the size (ms or us)?

For reference, I expect messages to be up to 500Kb.

Comment: Do your messages say how much data will follow?  Read those bytes, allocate a buffer that size, call `recv`, check the result from `recv` for how many bytes were received (or `-1` if there was an error, and `errno` for the particular error).  Otherwise, allocate the largest expected message, and check the `recv` result.

Comment: Size it one larger than the largest message you expect to receive. That way if you get one that size you know it may have been truncated, and all others haven’t. BUT you can’t receive 500kB with UDP. Nowhere near it.

Comment: @Eljay that approach works for TCP, but will generally not work for UDP. You have to read the entire datagram in a single read, there is no partial reading allowed, unless you use the `MSG_PEEK` flag to read the datagram without extracting it from the input buffer. But then you may as well just extract it since you would have to peek the whole thing anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> For reference, I expect messages to be up to 500Kb.

The maximum datagram payload size in UDP is 65507 bytes. If your application protocol has larger messages then it needs some way to split these messages into multiple UDP datagrams and handle packet loss, duplication and reordering when reconstructing the message.

> Can I check what is the message size of the next packet in the queue and resize buffer accordingly?

You can simply use a buffer of 64k since the datagrams cannot be larger.

Comment: 65507 for the payload.

Comment: … and in practice you are limited by the path MTU, as fragmentation increases the risk of packet loss. Some sources say the only reliable maximum is 534 bytes, which is the minimum that all hosts are required to support. Can’t remember whether that’s packet or payload, sorry.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich just to make sure, we are talking about IPC communication whithin the same CPU, no network. Is 64K still the limit?

Comment: @mu5e: the size of a UDP datagram is limited by the UDP protocol, which is the same no matter if local or remote peer. Se https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure where it shows that there is only 16bit to specify the size.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see different info here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38043/size-of-data-that-can-be-written-to-read-from-sockets

UNIX domain sockets probably support still more: you are probably just limited by memory in this case.

Comment: @mu5e: The question is about UDP, which is a transport protocol on top of IP. While a UNIX domain socket can be used as a datagram socket similar to UDP this isn't the same as actually using UDP. So what you observe with UNIX domain sockets cannot just be applied for UDP.